# When i can use navigationClick(),fieldchagedListner() or focusListner()?

Tags: blackberry, user-interface, event-handling

I am very confused with the Event Handling in Blackberry.
I facing many problems when i am using `navigationClick(),fieldchagedListner() or focusListner().`

Sometimes navigationClick() works and sometimes not.Same situation with other two.
So i want to know when and how i can use above event handling methods in BlackBerry.

Please help me to come out from this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**fieldChangedListener:** user has changed the state of the field and you want to listen that event. e.g. click on the buttonfield, text change in the editfield.

**focusListerner:** You just want to listen focus change event of the field.
e.g. FOCUS_GAINED, FOCUS_LOST

**navigationClick:** BitmapField is not click-able by default but if you want a click event for bitmapfield , you can use navigationCick to listen trackball press on the bitmapfield.

**Note:** FieldChangedListener and focusListener are just a [listener pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

using navigationClick you can create your own clickListener for buttonfield and using keychar() you can create your own textChangeListener for editfield.